# Migrating ASP Web Application to .Net Core with angular 6

Tags: c#, visual-studio, performance, angular6

I am planning to migrate a ASP Web Application Project with around 500 Pages to Angular 6.

I found that its taking around a minute to compile code when i make any changes in Visual code. The time taken is as shown below

Angular CLI Command:

```
**Ng-serve**    
Date: 2018-08-02T17:30:44.275Z
Hash: 75cd89291b80c102cec3
Time: 67316ms

chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 6.65 MB
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 227 kB
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 5.22 kB
chunk {scripts} scripts.js, scripts.js.map (scripts) 318 kB 
chunk {styles} styles.css, styles.css.map (styles) 287 kB
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 16.65 MB
Compiled successfully.
Compiling...
```

Date: 2018-08-02T17:29:14.497Z - Hash: 1878093f260b585faf8c - Time: 1155ms
5 unchanged chunks
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 567 kB [initial] [rendered]
Compiled successfully.
Compiling...

Project structure for my project:

[image]

What is suitable project structure for my scenario?

How can i reduce the compilation time of the angular project during development?

Comment: I believe your components should be large enough to be modules, build modules out of your components and lazy load the modules in your app-route setting

Comment: So Do you suggestion me to create modules in the same project or should i create different angular project ?. I want to make the project as light as possible to reduce the compilation time in development environment.

Comment: In our app we move e.g. controls to separate projects and create npm packages (ng-packagr) stored in a private repository (nexus server). Most of this projects include a separata ng app for test pages etc... that will not be included in npm package.